# HTML for Email Signature; Need text to go under table

Tags: html, email, signature

I am need of some help with a email signature that I am in the process of making. Could someone please point me in the right direction of what I need to do to make the "Please consider the environment before printing this email" appear below the table and not to the side of it as it seems to do by default.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>
        <div>
        <table width="620" border"0">
            <tbody>

                <!-- Main text & Logo -->
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="https://s14.postimg.org/bqnzp5681/Driven_Signature_Logo_v3.jpg" height="61" width="180"/></td>
                    <td><img src="https://s2.postimg.org/50ail0rzt/Signature_Break.jpg" height="80" width="2"/></td>
                    <td><p style="font-family:'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'; color:#7e7b7a; font-size:10px">
                    <span style="color: #3b3836; font-size:12px">Jack Kerry</span><br />
                    <span style="color: #7e7b7a; font-size:10px">Marketing/Admin Assistant</span><br />
                    E<span style="color: #ED7D31"> | </span>jack@driven-international.com<br />
                    T<span style="color: #ED7D31"> | </span>+44 1256 767 766<br />
                    F<span style="color: #ED7D31"> | </span>+44 1189 195 043<br />
                    A<span style="color: #ED7D31"> | </span>Acorn House, London Road, Hook. RG27 9DY. UK<br />
                    <td><img src="https://s2.postimg.org/50ail0rzt/Signature_Break.jpg" height="80" width="2"/></td>
                    </p></td>

                <!-- Social Media Icons --> 

                <td valign="middle"><table item-width="600" border="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jack-kerry-b2550a11a/"><img src="https://s12.postimg.org/t33ekd765/Driven_linkedin_logo.png" height="35" width="35"/></td>
                    <td><a href="https://twitter.com/DrivenInt"><img src="https://s12.postimg.org/iuaxejj4d/Driven_twitter_logo.png" height="35" width="35"/></td>
                    <td><a href="http://driven-international.com/"><img src="https://s12.postimg.org/7vznwcuj1/Driven_Website_link.png" height="35" width="35"/></td>
                    <td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJtVJ8uQtU7XHemdulN8KMg"><img src="https://s12.postimg.org/gsag0al59/Driven_Youtube_Logo.png" height="35" width="35"/></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>


        <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/61wphkbxp/recycle-logo2.png" height="20" width="20"/>
        <p style="font-family:'Arial, Helvetica, san-serif'; color: #7e7b7a; font-size:10px"> Please consider the environment before printing this email </p>



</body>  

</html>
```

Comment: You are not closing the outer <table>.

Comment: Please share image of HTML so we can get idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>
        <div>
        <table width="620" border"0">
            <tbody>

                <!-- Main text & Logo -->
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="https://s14.postimg.org/bqnzp5681/Driven_Signature_Logo_v3.jpg" height="61" width="180"/></td>
                    <td><img src="https://s2.postimg.org/50ail0rzt/Signature_Break.jpg" height="80" width="2"/></td>
                    <td><p style="font-family:'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'; color:#7e7b7a; font-size:10px">
                    <span style="color: #3b3836; font-size:12px">Jack Kerry</span><br />
                    <span style="color: #7e7b7a; font-size:10px">Marketing/Admin Assistant</span><br />
                    E<span style="color: #ED7D31"> | </span>jack@driven-international.com<br />
                    T<span style="color: #ED7D31"> | </span>+44 1256 767 766<br />
                    F<span style="color: #ED7D31"> | </span>+44 1189 195 043<br />
                    A<span style="color: #ED7D31"> | </span>Acorn House, London Road, Hook. RG27 9DY. UK<br />
                    <td><img src="https://s2.postimg.org/50ail0rzt/Signature_Break.jpg" height="80" width="2"/></td>
                    </p></td>

                <!-- Social Media Icons --> 

                <td valign="middle"><table item-width="600" border="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jack-kerry-b2550a11a/"><img src="https://s12.postimg.org/t33ekd765/Driven_linkedin_logo.png" height="35" width="35"/></td>
                    <td><a href="https://twitter.com/DrivenInt"><img src="https://s12.postimg.org/iuaxejj4d/Driven_twitter_logo.png" height="35" width="35"/></td>
                    <td><a href="http://driven-international.com/"><img src="https://s12.postimg.org/7vznwcuj1/Driven_Website_link.png" height="35" width="35"/></td>
                    <td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJtVJ8uQtU7XHemdulN8KMg"><img src="https://s12.postimg.org/gsag0al59/Driven_Youtube_Logo.png" height="35" width="35"/></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        </table>
        </div>


        <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/61wphkbxp/recycle-logo2.png" height="20" width="20"/>
    <div>
        <p style="font-family:'Arial, Helvetica, san-serif'; color: #7e7b7a; font-size:10px"> Please consider the environment before printing this email </p>
</div>


</body>  

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks man! It's embarrassing how long I was stuck on this :D